# Umbraco multi-node tree picker selection issue

Tags: components, selection, umbraco, media, picker

I have custom data type based on uComponents's Multi-Node Tree Picker.

I use it already in one document type and it workes fine as below:

[image]

I now added the same data type to another document type but when I go to the page to add some nodes I just get all folders in red and upon clicking the node doesn't get selected:

[image]

I created another data type using the same Multi-node Tree picker and added it to the new page instead of the old one but nothing changed. The still look the same in the page edit and still cannot select any node.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a different MNP datatype for the type of nodes you want to select.  Make sure to review the following attributes of the datatype:

Node selection type

```
XPath type (if the selection type is xpath)
xPath expression
XPath filter type - you'll probably want to set this to disabled but depends if you want to filter out some types
```

Comment: I disabled XPath filter type. Thanks for the tip

Comment: If my answer helped you please click the green check mark next to it in order to accept it so that future visitors can be helped as well.  If other answers also contributed you can also click the up arrow to give them credit.  I don't think you have accepted any answers to your 31 questions to date.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably filtered the allowed subnodes to be selected. i.e. you have enabled the 'XPath filter type' and provided some specific document type for this MultiNodePicker.
I do agree with lucuma, Its better to have different MNPs for different uses!

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue but solved it by setting "XPath filter type" Disable (Checked).

if you checked "XPath filter type" Enable option Checked in that case your items will shown in content editor red color as you described above.

I am using same Datatype for multiple node.

Thanks,

Salman Ansari